# remove qtip when element is removed from dom

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I apply a tooltip with qtip2 via a jquery .on event on mouseover, on img and div elements. Those elements sometimes need to be removed from the DOM while the qtip is still showing, and this removal is not under my control. 
The result is the qtip stays there forever. How can I remove the qtip when its associated element is removed?

EDIT
underlying elements are not removed with jquery's .remove() but with innerHTML=.. so qtip2 automatic removal is not working here.

Answer (score 3):

As you are asking for the QTip2 way, here it is. In your QTip2-initialization, add this:

```
events: {
    //this hide event will remove the qtip element from body and all assiciated events, leaving no dirt behind.
    hide: function(event, api) {
        api.destroy(true); // Destroy it immediately
    }
}
```

Tested with QTip 2.2.0. [source](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2/issues/458)

Answer (score 1):

If you can update your qTip to the most recent nightly build. Then try adding this to your qTip creation:

```
$('#element').qtip({
   content : {stuff},
   style : {stuff},
   position: {stuff},
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'click',
   onHide: function() { $(this).qtip('destroy'); }
});
```

You can also take a look here:

[[Solved] How to destroy a qtip when the original element is removed](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-how-to-destroy-a-qtip-when-the-original-element-is-removed)

[[Solved] clear qtips when rebuilding DOM](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-how-to-destroy-a-qtip-when-the-original-element-is-removed)

Comment: sorry, there is never a mouseout. The mouse doesn't move. For example I click on a grid cell and the div gets removed and replaced by another element like a <select>.

Comment: These links are about removing dom elements with jquery's remove(). That is not the case with me.

Comment: you can change the show/hide events with a 'click' parameter.

Comment: As the creator of qTip said: Move over to qTip2 (you already have this), which implements a $.remove() override identical to that in jQuery UI, which triggers the removal of any bound qTips when an element that has qTip or any parent elements are removed.

Comment: I am already using qtip2. qtip2 when using jquery remove. I have this.innerHTML=... which doesn't work with qtip2. I'll try the click.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall well you're right. I destroy all qtips on click and with a combination of mouseover/mouseout I'm getting somewhere. A bit expensive on resources but the only way it seems.